# Django: ModelForm validation not working

Tags: django, modelform

I am trying to create a user registration form. I know there is a built-in user registration form in Django but I am challenging myself to create one.

I created a ModelForm from User model and wrote few methods to validate and confirm password . But it seems that the methods, `clean_password()` and `clean()` are not being executed by `form.is_valid()` at `views.py`.

Below is the snippet of RegistrationForm -

```
class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    re_password = CharField(widget = PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'Re-password'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
                'username' : TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'Username'}),
                'email' : EmailInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'Email'}),
                'password' : PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'Password'})
                }

        def clean_password(self):
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if len(password) < 6:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Password not long enough. Should be >= 6')
            return password

        def clean(self):
            if not self.cleaned_data['password'] == self.cleaned_data['re_password']:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords should match")
            return self.cleaned_data
```

**Additional question**

The `password` does not seem to be encrypted by `form.save()`. I had to create new User instance and call its `.set_password()` method to encrypt it. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Indentation Error**. The validators are inside the `META` instead of `RegistrationForm`.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about having to set the password. Your view should look something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)  # Don't waste the database write
    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
```

#### Update

1. you need to remove your `clean_password` method and add `validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(6)]` to the `password` model field's declaration (or simply define `password` as a field on the form manually, and provide `min_length=6` to it).
2. You need to dedent your `clean` method by 1 level or it will never be called (it's currently being defined as a method on your `Meta` class).

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner than what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can define min_length of password field in `__init__` method of form, like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['password'].min_length = 6
```

In second, yes, this right way